# Auto Text Summarization: Web application using Django/python?

Tags: python, django, project

I am going to develop a auto text summarization tool as my FYP. I am going to use Python and it's going to be a web application. Since, there would be no database involved in my tool is it a good idea to use Django? Can anyone recommend any other framework? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no database in your application then you presumably won't be using Django's ORM, which is one main reason to use it rather than something lighter.

Having said that, if you're familiar with Django, use Django. If you're not and are looking for a Python web framework, how about something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)? The templating module (Jinja2, I think) is a bit more powerful than Django's templates.

Comment: I am familiar with Django. I will develop the application using Django.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if database is involved or not, but for overall web development, it's an easy to use framework.